# advance in a string

Tags: java, string, char

I am trying to go through every char of a string and get the first char, which can be found in the 1st, 2nd, ... space. So, this is what I have:

```
  String add1 = "A2B";
  String add2 = "BDR";
  String result = "BFT";

  String line = add1+add2+result;
  char aChar;
  for(int i=0; i<aChar; i++) {
    aChar = line.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(aChar);
  }
```

I think that I am a little bit confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. I want to put the strings(add1,add2,result) in one string. 2. I want to scan every char of the string to find the first char. Because as you can see in the strings there might be a number and not a char. Basically I just want to get the first char of the string. Thank you

Comment: By first char you mean first letter?

Comment: Yes Sr. Thanks for your help, I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop should read

```
for(int i=0 ; i < line.length(); i++) {
    aChar = line.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(aChar);

}
```

Comment: Very close, can't believe I was that close. Thank you

Comment: @Bart: Note that it would be better to declare the variable *inside* the loop, as per my answer. In general you should limit the scope of your variables as tightly as possible, for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're nearly there - you just need help with the limit:

```
for (int index = 0; index < line.length(); index++) {
    char c = line.charAt(index);
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Is that what you were trying to achieve? (Note that this all happens *after* what you mentioned in your comment - which is just simple string concatenation.)

Comment: Yes, Thank you that is what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rewrite your for statement as:

```
for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++)  {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
for(int i=0; i < line.length(); i++){
    char aChar = line.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(aChar);
}
```

BTW: Your code formatting is atrocious

Comment: Thank you for your help, yep that is my talent.